# Abstract way to call functions with javascript. Can it be done?

Tags: javascript, performance, function, user-defined-functions

Is it possible to conditionally call functions in javascript by using a string parameter to specify the name of the function needed to be called?

```
function test1(){
    // something
}

function test2(){
   // Something
}
function test3(){
   // something
}
var callString = 'test1' // test1 or test2 or test3

callString();
/* Obviously this is an error, but
coul this be formatted so that JS,
could call the function of callString?*/
```

Comment: yes, it is. So what is your [*actual* question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sure, if you structure it properly.  You can use array-like (or bracket) notation:

```
var functions = {
    test1: function () {},
    test2: function () {},
    test3: function () {}
}

var callString = 'test1';
functions[callString](); // run functions.test1()

callString = 'test2';
functions[callString](); // run functions.test2()
```

Answer (score 0):

If the `functions` are in `global context`, as every `global function` or `global variable` is `key` of `window` object.

```js
function test1() {
  alert('Hi!');
}

function test2() {
  alert('Hi!');
}

function test3() {
  alert('Hi!');
}
var callString = 'test1';

window[callString]();
```